# Populating table using Vector in netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, sql, exception, netbeans

I'm doing a project related to blood donation, this is my searching frame where anyone can search whether blood is available.
The issue is that I've two tables named user_don where the admission number and day month year of the last donation is saved, and name_don_det where the admission number name phone etc are saved.
I want to retrieve data from two tables and show it at a time together using vector or something else.. This is what I've:

```
user_view(String d1, String d2, String d3) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    initComponents();
    int a = Integer.parseInt(d1);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(d2);
    int c = Integer.parseInt(d3);
    int year=a;
    int month=b;
    int date=c;
    String query;
    String query1;
    if(b<=6)
    {
        year=a-1;
        month=b+6;
        query="Select * from user_don_det where Year<="+ year +" and Month<="+ month +"";
        query1="SELECT * FROM `user_det` WHERE `Admission`=(Select Admission From user_don_det where Year<="+ year +" and Month<="+ month +")";
    }
    else
    {
        month=b-6;
        query="Select * from user_don_det where Month<="+ month +" or Year<="+ year +"";
        query1="SELECT * FROM `user_det` WHERE `Admission`=(Select Admission From user_don_det where Month<="+ month +")";
    }

    blooddonation.dbconnectivity db=new blooddonation.dbconnectivity();
     ResultSet rs=db.q_execute(query);      
     ResultSet rs1=db.q_execute(query1);

    Vector data=new Vector();
   while(rs.next())
    {
        Vector row=new Vector();
        row.addElement(rs.getInt(1));
        row.addElement(rs.getInt(2));
        row.addElement(rs.getInt(3));
        row.addElement(rs.getInt(4));

        data.addElement(row);
    }
    while(rs1.next())
    {Vector row=new Vector();
        row.addElement(rs1.getString(1));
        row.addElement(rs1.getString(2));
        row.addElement(rs1.getString(6));
        row.addElement(rs1.getInt(8));
        data.addElement(row);
    }


    Vector head=new Vector();
    head.addElement("Admission No");
    head.addElement("Date");
    head.addElement("Month");
    head.addElement("Year");
    head.addElement("Name");
    head.addElement("Email");
    head.addElement("Sex");
    head.addElement("Phone");

    DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel(data,head);
    tab.setModel(model);
```

}

Here is the current error status :

```
SEVERE: null
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:988)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:974)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:804)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6986)
    at blooddonation.user_view.<init>(user_view.java:55)
    at blooddonation.user_fscreen$5.actionPerformed(user_fscreen.java:263)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
```

Comment: Which line is `user_view.java:55` ? Post an [MCVE] : post the bare minimum to show your issue. 
(Writing a minimal case is a good debugging technique. In doing so you are likely to solve your problem.)

Answer (score 0):

Error was solved..
IN was to be used instead of =